# Magento 2.2.1 - how to give discount on payment methods?

Tags: layout, template, payment-methods, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.2

I go to `Magento 2.2.1` `Admin > Marketing > Promotions > Cart Price Rules` and create a new Rule: Conditions.

Option "Payment Method" is not showing up in Conditions Tab. I want to give some discount on specific payment methods.

Screenshot : [image]

Please help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have debug core code for this issue and find bug in file `Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address.php` at line number:`58`

**Solution:**

Replace code in function `loadAttributeOptions` **from**

```
public function loadAttributeOptions()
{
    $attributes = [
        'base_subtotal' => __('Subtotal'),
        'total_qty' => __('Total Items Quantity'),
        'weight' => __('Total Weight'),
        'shipping_method' => __('Shipping Method'),
        'postcode' => __('Shipping Postcode'),
        'region' => __('Shipping Region'),
        'region_id' => __('Shipping State/Province'),
        'country_id' => __('Shipping Country'),
    ];

    $this->setAttributeOption($attributes);

    return $this;
}
```

**To**

```
public function loadAttributeOptions()
{
        $attributes = [
            'base_subtotal' => __('Subtotal'),
            'total_qty' => __('Total Items Quantity'),
            'weight' => __('Total Weight'),
            'shipping_method' => __('Shipping Method'),
            'payment_method' => __('Payment Method'),
            'postcode' => __('Shipping Postcode'),
            'region' => __('Shipping Region'),
            'region_id' => __('Shipping State/Province'),
            'country_id' => __('Shipping Country'),
        ];

        $this->setAttributeOption($attributes);

        return $this;
}
```

**Note:** First override model file `Address.php` in local after update above code in file.

**Override model file code:**

> app\code\AR\SalesRule\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2015 Ccc. All rights reserved.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="AR_SalesRule" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_SalesRule"/>
        </sequence>
   </module>
</config>
```

> app\code\AR\SalesRule\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <preference for="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address" type="AR\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address" />
</config>
```

> app\code\AR\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace AR\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition;

class Address extends \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address
{
    /**
     * Load attribute options
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function loadAttributeOptions()
    {
        $attributes = [
            'base_subtotal' => __('Subtotal'),
            'total_qty' => __('Total Items Quantity'),
            'weight' => __('Total Weight'),
            'shipping_method' => __('Shipping Method'),
            'payment_method' => __('Payment Method'),
            'postcode' => __('Shipping Postcode'),
            'region' => __('Shipping Region'),
            'region_id' => __('Shipping State/Province'),
            'country_id' => __('Shipping Country'),
        ];

        $this->setAttributeOption($attributes);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

> app\code\AR\SalesRule\registration.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
       'AR_SalesRule',
       __DIR__
 );
```

**After run below command:**

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: Hi Abdul, I have tried to override the model file Address.php, but no changes are showing up in backend conditions. i have created Module\SalesRule\etc\di.xml and Module\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition in Address.php with the above changes but no payment methods are showing up.

Comment: have u checked with core code? Please put code in core file and check for testing. is it working in core file?

Comment: Hi Abdul it is working when i made changes in core files, but why it is not working in overriding Address.php ? Could you please update the code with override files. Help is appreciated :)

Comment: I think you are overriding wrong way. can u please share your overriding code?

Comment: I have created ModuleName/SalesRule with subfolders - etc and Model
Then etc/di.xml and Model/Rule/Condition/Address.php. I have copied the file Address.php from the orginal one and made changes mentioned above. In Comments how to add code?

di.xml code >  <preference for="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition" type="ModuleName\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition" />

Comment: I have checked override code my end and it is working fine.

Comment: Updated ans pls check

Comment: It is working now :) Thanks for the help Abdul.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Abdul for the hint and debugging.

I think using a [plugin/interceptor](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) for adding some extra functionality to core files should be considered first. If that fails or is not possible, go with the override method. With interceptors you won't loose future updates to `Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Adress::loadAttributeOptions()`.

If Magento adds some new options to the core function you'll be missing the option in your overriding model so you need to touch your code again.

At least if using the override method i would try to call the parent method and merge the base options with my new option, something like that

```php
parent::loadAttributeOptions();

$this->setAttributeOption(array_merge(
    $this->getAttributeOption(), 
    ['payment_method' => __('Payment Method'))
);
```

---

#### Example for adding "Payment Method" to cart rules using a plugin/interceptor

In your custom extension add following files:

- app/code/***YOUR/EXTENSION***/etc/di.xml
- app/code/***YOUR/EXTENSION***/Plugin/SalesRule/AdressPlugin.php

**app/code/Your/Extension/etc/di.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address">
        <plugin name="Your_Extension_Plugin_SalesRule_Address" type="Your\Extension\Plugin\SalesRule\AddressPlugin" sortOrder="10" disabled="false" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Your/Extension/Plugin/SalesRule/AdressPlugin.php:**

```php
<?php

namespace Your\Extension\Plugin\SalesRule;

use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address;

class AddressPlugin
{
    /**
     * Your Description.
     *
     * @param  Address
     *
     * @return Address
     */
    public function afterLoadAttributeOptions(Address $subject)
    {
        $options = $subject->getAttributeOption();

        if (!array_key_exists('payment_method', $options)) {
            $subject->setAttributeOption(array_merge($options, ['payment_method' => __('Payment Method')]));
        }

        return $subject;
    }
}
```