# Payment wise Discount not showing on checkout cart page?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2

I try with this link 
1) [Magento 2.2.1 - how to give discount on payment methods?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/204532/magento-2-2-1-how-to-give-discount-on-payment-methods)
2) [Magento 2 - discount depend on Payment Method does not work](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128580/magento-2-discount-depend-on-payment-method-does-not-work)

But I can not see Discount on checkout/cart page after create Rule. If any one have Suggestion please share it.

Comment: Can you please say me which type of rule you want?

Comment: i get Discount in email and also see discount from order grid but its not show only when user select any payment method from front end @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd.

Comment: In simple words discount not showing up in cart total section in front end @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd.